# how to restore TFS project?

Tags: sql-server-2005, tfs, tfs-2005

I deleted a project folder in TFS, without realizing and checked in pending changes as well.

The local project copy was in offline state and I mistakingly made it online. Because of this I lost the only copy I had. Is there a way to restore the project? I know this is foolish and careless but I made the mistake already. Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TFS: Restore deleted folders and items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479441/tfs-restore-deleted-folders-and-items)

Comment: The question is, if you just deleted a folder (this is just a flag of visibility) or if you deleted the whole TeamProject (all sources, work items ...). If you deleted the TeamProject your only option would be a database backup you have made before the project was deleted. Otherwise it is gone.

Answer (score 1):

check this : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479441/tfs-restore-deleted-folders-and-items)

In Team Explorer (in Visual Studio): Tools | Options | Source Control | Visual Studio Team Foundation Server and select Show Deleted Items...

Then in source control explorer you'll see the items greyed out. You can right click on them and Undelete. (This option will only be available if they, after the undelete, will be included in your current workspace).

Alternatively using the TFS PowerToys you can look at history and right click to select "Rollback Entire Changeset": this will create pending changes to revert the changes of the selected changeset.