# TFS 2017 Clean up accidental folder creation

Tags: tfs

I have created a folder in TFS via Branch.  The Branch copied the individual items to the folder when I intended it to copy them into a folder under the branch.  So, I tried to delete everything and start over, but I get "folder already exists" messages, even though they are deleted.  Is there a "seriously, delete them" option?

Comment: are you using tfvc as your source control or git?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming  you are using TFVC. Deleting the folder in TFS will only actually perform a "soft delete". The branch will still exist complete with all of it's history, except it will **be hidden**. You could show the deleted items in VS follow this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10479797/5391065).

If you want to **permanently deletes version-controlled files** from Team Foundation version control, need to perform a [tf destroy command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/destroy-command-team-foundation-version-control?view=vsts).

```
tf destroy [/keephistory] <itemspec1>[;<versionspec>][<itemspec2>...<itemspecN>] 
[/stopat:<versionspec>] [/preview] [/startcleanup] [/noprompt] [/silent] [/login:username,[password]] [/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl]]
```

If the issue still exists after destroyed the folder. Also check if it's a client issue, like a conflicting Visual Studio add-in. Try to [clear TFS and VS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/). Which should do the trick.