# Should a TFS branch be deleted before destroying it?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

After viewing a **deleted** branch's folder in explorer.exe with **TFSSCExplorerExtension** installed, I noticed it's green arrow icon would no longer be visible. However, after **destroying** a branch *without first deleting it*, the green arrow was still visible.

I was able to delete the folder with it's green icon still displaying without any warnings or errors, so am hoping this was a simple view refresh issue and not state inconsistency.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't **have to** delete a branch before destroying it in TFS. You **could directly destroy the branch without deleting it**. However:

> Before you run **tf destroy** without the `/keephistory` option, we
>   **recommend that you first delete the files you want to destroy.**
>
> After you delete the files you can synchronize the Team Foundation
>   warehouse. Otherwise, the warehouse will not be synchronized with the
>   destroyed items.

For more detail information, see [Delete Files and Folders from Version Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/delete-restore-files-folders?view=vsts).

---

Deleting the folder in TFS will only actually perform a "soft delete". The branch will still exist complete with all of it's history, except it will **be hidden**. You could show the deleted items in VS follow this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10479797/5391065).

If you want to **permanently deletes version-controlled files** from Team Foundation version control, need to perform a [tf destroy command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/destroy-command-team-foundation-version-control?view=vsts).

```
tf destroy [/keephistory] <itemspec1>[;<versionspec>][<itemspec2>...<itemspecN>] 
[/stopat:<versionspec>] [/preview] [/startcleanup] [/noprompt] [/silent] [/login:username,[password]] [/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl]]
```

Comment: Is there an instance where a destroy should be performed without first deleting (I'm trying to figure out why destroy doesn't implicitly delete if not already performed, since doing so could result in desynchronized files)?