# TFS Folder deleted project

Tags: tfs

i have deleted project from TFS but now i see a folder that has no pending changes or anything in it but the name of the folder is now starting as D7311f850 and I can not delete it from the list. Is there a way we can?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be some cached folder in Visual Studio. You could just try to close VS and  clean the client TFS caches, then open visual studio again.

TFS:

```
C:\Users\{your account}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\{version}\Cache
```

---

Deleting the folder in TFS will only actually perform a "soft delete". The branch will still exist complete with all of it's history, except it will **be hidden**. You could show the deleted items in VS follow this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10479797/5391065).

If you want to **permanently deletes version-controlled files** from Team Foundation version control, need to perform a [tf destroy command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/destroy-command-team-foundation-version-control?view=vsts).

```
tf destroy [/keephistory] <itemspec1>[;<versionspec>][<itemspec2>...<itemspecN>] 
[/stopat:<versionspec>] [/preview] [/startcleanup] [/noprompt] [/silent] [/login:username,[password]] [/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl]]
```

If above not work and you do not need the  folders any more, you could also destroy the file and clean the cache again.